# Is it possible to stream audio picked up from a mobile device to a webserver in real-time?

Tags: android, ios, swift, audio

Thinking of creating an app to allow people to podcast from their phones using the built-in microphone. I'm thinking this is possible, hence Facebook Live, but I wanted to know what I would need server side and logistically to build this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is quite possible, server side you'd need to set up a server socket to accept connection from users, and then stream the audio over it. Logistically, you need your phones to have the server's IP address configured in the application, they connect to that address and transmit their audio streams, as they come.

This is basic networking/Socket management, for future reference, don't ask vague questions like "is it possible to...".